# VB6 - Bulk insert objects from memory into SQL

Tags: sql-server, vb6, bulkinsert

I know it's possible to do a bulk insert from a file like this:

```
strSQL = "BULK INSERT Northwind.dbo.[Order Details] 
          FROM 'e:\My Documents\TextFiles\OrderDetails.txt' " & _
         "WITH ( FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n' )"
```

But I can't seem to find a way to insert an object that's in memory instead. Is this possible?

Comment: SQL ≠ SQL Server.  You could improve your tags.

Comment: @Bob77 Tags improved on your suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution ended up being to build a COM object in C# that does the bulk insert and then leveraging that COM object in the VB6 project.

Answer (score 0):

The file must be visible from the SQL Server itself and its account must have access rights (if you are using SQL Server):

From http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx

*BULK INSERT can import data from a disk (including network, floppy disk, hard disk, and so on). 'data_file' must specify a valid path from the server on which SQL Server is running. If data_file is a remote file, specify the Universal Naming Convention (UNC) name. A UNC name has the form \Systemname\ShareName\Path\FileName. For example, \SystemX\DiskZ\Sales\update.txt.*

Answer (score 0):

You can use a table variable to populate a temporary table, then use a MERGE statement to process that temp table into the target database.

T-SQL Merge statement docs here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx